# Не компилируется код, написанный на ассемблере

Tags: c++, ассемблер

пытаюсь продублировать код, написанный на С++, на языке ассемблера, но как-то не выходит

код на С+:

```
int main(){
    short a = 4;
    short b = 3;
    short c = 6;
    short d = 10;
    short sum = 0;
    short x = -4;
    int sum1 = 0;
    short y ;
    for (int x = -4; x < 4; x++){
        if (x < 0){
            int f = (b + c*x)/a;
            sum1 += f;
        }
        if (x == 0){
            int f = -(5 + b*c);
            sum1 += f;
        }
        if (x > 0){
            int f = (d*d*x)/(c+3);
            sum1 += f;
        }

    }
    cout << "Сумма на c++ = " << sum1 << endl;
}
```

Код на ассемблере:

*

```
asm {
    proverka:
        mov cx, x
        cmp cx, 5
        cmp cx, 0
        jl cycle1
        je cycle2
        jg cycle3
        }

    asm{
    cycle1:
        mov cx, x
        mov ax, cx
        imul ax, c
        add ax, b
        mov bl, a
        div bl
        mov y, al
        add cx, 1
        mov x, cx
    }

    asm {
        jmp proverka
    }


    asm{
    cycle2:
        mov ax, b
        imul ax, c
        add ax, 5
        mov dx, -1
        imul ax, dx
        mov y, ax
    }
    asm {
        jmp proverka
    }

    asm{
    cycle3:
        mov cx, x
        mov ax, d
        imul ax, a
        imul ax, x
        mov bl, c
        add bl, 3
        idiv bl
        mov y, bl
        mov cx, 1
        mov x, cx
    }

    asm {
        jmp proverka
    }




    asm {
        vihod:
        mov sum, ax


    }

    cout << "sum = " << sum << endl ;
```

Comment: Что "не выходит", какие ошибки выдает? Второй блок кода это именно так у вас файл с кодом выглядит? Как компилируете?

Comment: Unsupported relocation of undefined symbol 'L__MSASMLABEL_.0__cycle1'

Comment: Ну, во-первых, весь код должен быть в одном asm блоке (ассемблерной вставке), скорее всего компилятор из одного блока asm не видит меток в другом блоке.

Comment: А как разделить циклы?

Comment: Никак, в ассемблере нет циклов, есть только код, метки и переходы.

Answer (score 0):

Есть сайт https://gcc.godbolt.org/ -- Compiler Explorer
Если Ваш исходник компилируется, Вы его в левое окно сбрасываете, а в правом получаете код на ассемблере.
Или просто скомпилируйте свой код с ключом вывода ассемблерного текста.